# sp_helpdb: how CONVERT created DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I like `sp_helpdb`, it gives me the chance to have the big picture.

I found a blog that shows [how to easily edit it](http://zarez.net/?p=2285).

BTW, I would like to order the results by creation date. In order to do so I have to CONVERT the "created" column from `Apr  7 2017` to `2017-04-07 00:00:00`.

So I insert `sp_helpdb` into a temporary table but my conversion (`CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),created,120)`) is not working:

```
CREATE TABLE #db_details (name nvarchar(128), db_size nvarchar(50),owner nvarchar(128),db_id int,created varchar(128),status nvarchar(2000),compatibility_level int)

INSERT INTO #db_details EXEC sp_helpdb
SELECT *
FROM #db_details
ORDER BY  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),created,120) asc

DROP TABLE #db_details
```

I'm following [a guide](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) that is just so easy! Where am I wrong?

Comment: BTW, what does "my conversion is not working" mean?

Comment: Date is not converted from `Apr  7 2017` to `2017-04-07 00:00:00`

Comment: Right, because you’re converting a string to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #db_details (name nvarchar(128), db_size nvarchar(50),owner nvarchar(128),db_id int,created varchar(128),status nvarchar(2000),compatibility_level int)

INSERT INTO #db_details EXEC sp_helpdb
SELECT name,db_size,owner,db_id,CONVERT(datetime,created,111) as New_Created,status,compatibility_level
FROM #db_details
ORDER BY  New_Created asc

DROP TABLE #db_details
```

Answer (score 2):

(1) You're converting something that's already a string into, well, the same string. The style number is completely irrelevant in this case; that is used if you are converting a string to a *date/time* or vice-versa.

(2) Inserting with an `ORDER BY` is meaningless, since that ordering isn't remembered when other queries later query from that table. You need the `ORDER BY` on the outer query if your intention is to ultimately return results to the client in that order. Try changing the query in the stored procedure to the following (and stop moving this output between more and more #temp tables):

```
select name = dbname,
    db_size = dbsize,
    owner = owner,
    dbid = dbid,
    created = created,
    status = dbdesc,
    compatibility_level = cmptlevel
from  #spdbdesc
order by CONVERT(datetime, dbname, 107);
```

Note that this conversion won't work if the session populating the #temp table is running in certain languages when they differ from the server language. For example, on a US English instance, if you first run this:

```
SET LANGUAGE Français;
```

The temporary table will be filled with English dates, like:

```
Apr 7 2008
```

But French doesn't know what "Apr" is, so the `CONVERT` will yield the following error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 9
>   
> La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites.

On SQL Server 2012 and higher (please always tag with the version you are using), you can use [`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) instead, to be safe. This will eliminate the error, but it means the data will be unordered for sessions with incompatible language settings.